# Best approach to copy table from one dataset to another in google big query using Dataflow and Java

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

What's the best way to copy big query table from one project to another using Dataflow. I did that using CopyJobConfiguration but, for that we always need to raise job creation access on the other project. So I am looking for the best, optimal and economical solution to copy data. On GCP I couldn't find the recommended approach other than JobCopyConfiguration.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the best way is to directly using `Bigquery` to copy a table from one project to another, no need to `Dataflow` in this case if you don't have business rules and tranformations.

You can use for example `gcloud` sdk and `bq` :

```bash
bq cp project1:dataset1.table1 project2:dataset2.table2
```

You can also directly use the `Bigquery` console from the `GUI` to do that.

You must using an identity that has the needed privileges on the two projects.

Comment: Exactly. You would only need Dataflow if you want to apply complex transformations / external sources. Even if you have simple transformations, you could use BigQuery to create a table based on a specific query (e.g., `CREATE TABLE project2:dataset2.table2 AS (SELECT * FROM project1:dataset1.table1`). Please check [Data definition language (DDL) statements in Google Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_table_statement) for a reference.

Comment: I agree with you @BrunoVolpato